# How to use mysqli_stmt_bind_param for integers, boolean, etc

Tags: php, data-binding, parameters, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am trying to use this method to bind the parameters to their specific types:

mysqli_stmt_bind_param(mysqli_stmt stmt, string types, mixed &var1 [, mixed &...])

I understand that the second parameter is a string of types where

```
* s is for strings
* d is for decimals
* i is for integers
* b is for blob
```

I'm not sure what "blob" is.

Now my question is, how could I bind boolean-type variables into this method? Is there such a way to do that?

More information below.
These are my variables:
(roomType, roomPrice, roomQty, numBeds, smokingAvail, accessibleRm)

```
   roomType: string coming from web form
   roomPrice: decimal coming from a web form 
   roomQty: integer coming from web form
   numBeds: integer coming from web form
   smokingAvail: Boolean coming from web form
   accessibleRm: Boolean coming from web form
```

Comment: boolean would be an `i` as you should be passing 1 or 0

Answer (score 4):

You can use `string` for all the types. Mysql will sort them out.

Answer (score 0):

To pass boolean you should use i as well:
if you pass string it always consider it as something which is not equal to false (in the case of boolean unless you pass empty string)

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare ('some query');
$stmt->bind_param("dsi",$price,$name,$sex);
```

and to pass integer i
and for decimal d